# what is SDKDDKVer.h for?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

All project created with MSVC have stdafx, which is precompiled headers, which I know what they are but what about targetver.h ? It includes SDKDDKVer.h, and I can't find what is that header about.

What is this for ?

Comment: Mostly it defines `_WIN32_WINNT` and `WINVER`. It does other things, but that's its most important task.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`targetver.h` and `SDKDDKVer.h` are used to control what functions, constants, etc. are included into your code from the Windows headers, based on the OS that you want your program to support. I believe that `targetver.h` sets defaults to using the latest version of Windows unless the defines are specified elsewhere.

`SDKDDKVer.h` is the header file that actually defines the `#defines` that represent each version of Windows, IE, etc.

Comment: The `targetver.h` file is autogenerated when you create the project and only includes two lines: `#pragma once` and `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>`, so basically it does nothing that including SDKDDKVer.h on its own doesn't do..

Comment: @d7samurai well it does nothing by default, but you can specify the target version in `targetver.h`, and you're supposed to do that before calling `SDKDDKVer.h`. It's just a file that allows you to do so.

Comment: When you create a Windows Desktop application using a Visual Studio wizard, the resulting `.rc` resource file may include the following:

`#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif`

In such applications it is best to maintain a `targetver.h` file to define `_WIN32_WINNT` and `WINVER`, rather than defining these within `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 3):

Line 193 of the `SDKDDKVer.h` (in SDK 8.1) states:

*"if versions aren't already defined, default to most current"*

This comment is specifically referring to the `_WIN32_WINNT` and `NTDDI_VERSION` macros.

So..

1. `SDKDDKVer.h` applies default values unless the macros have already been defined
2. the following code can be used to explicitly define the macros

- `#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0601`
- `#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06010000`

3. Interestingly enough, the `SDKDDKVer.h` header file has 'constant' values defined for all of the SDK versions. For example:

- `#define _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP 0x0501`
- `#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 0x0601`
- `#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8 0x0602`

4. One convention is to define `_WIN32_WINNT` and `NTDDI_VERSION`in a header file called `TargetVer.h`, which you would reference in your pre-compiled header `StdAfx.h`.

#ADDTIONAL READING#

- [Update WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170)
- [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [What does the Target Platform Version mean for a VS C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621646/what-does-the-target-platform-version-mean-for-a-vs-c-project)

Comment: Superb, usable answer! It is a pity that those constants are not available before including `<SDKDDKVer.h>`.

Comment: @Liviu You don't need to include this header before. You can for example #define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN10 even if NTDDI_WIN10 is not yet known to the preprocessor.