# Windows SDK control available functions

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Function `AddDllDirectory` was added to Windows 7 in one of the updates.

I'm using Windows 10 SDK headers in my c++ application. Is it possible to configure them to show only functions available in first Windows 7 version (without any updates) ?

I read about defines of:

```
WINVER, _WIN32_WINNT
```

I tried to set them to:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06010000
```

or even:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x600
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000
```

, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Wrong number(s) see:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, I have updated my answer. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The NTDDI_VERSION macro uses a 32-bit number that includes service pack information. The [older defines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070411-00/?p=27283) (WINVER, _WIN32_WINNT, _WIN32_WINDOWS, and _WIN32_IE) is just a 16-bit number, typically in hex: `0xaabb` where aa is the Windows major version and bb is the minor version.

The correct value for Windows 7 is therefore `0x0601` for these defines and `0x06010000` is just for NTDDI_VERSION. The [SdkDdkver.h header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539391/what-is-sdkddkver-h-for) also provides macros like _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 and NTDDI_WIN7 where the version numbers are listed for you.

Comment: The [AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) API call was introduced in a [Security Advisory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2533623/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remot) update. I doubt that `NTDDI_VERSION` has any provision for that.

Comment: Another relevant URL: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070410-00/?p=27313